# How do you manage web developers remotely?

Tags: project-management

I'm the leader of a small web development team, and I have a feeling that we will have a couple telecommuters joining the team pretty soon (either new employees, or existing employees that will begin telecommuting).  Any idea how to effectively manage and collaborate with developers working remotely?

Most of the work we do is client-driven.  We're doing agile development (or our version of it, anyway), but since it's mostly client work, we can't really assign a feature to a developer and set them lose for a week or two like we might be able to with a desktop app or something like that.  The biggest problem we have when people occasionally work from home is collaborating - it's tough to work together without the benefit of a whiteboard and hand-waving.

It seems like software development is perfect for telecommuting, but I haven't been able to find many good resources about the practical aspects of working remotely within a development team.  Has anyone else had any experience with this?

Comment: How many times a month can you see them face-to-face?

Comment: Let's say once.  I'd like to figure out how to do this with people who are local but working from home, and with people on the other side of the country who won't be able to come in as often.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I freelance a lot and in doing so work remotely a lot of the time. These are the things that make my life as easy as possible (so might be things you want to "suggest"). I think they're mostly common-sense, but you never know...

1. [Everyone] Communicate well. When you're having a conversation face-to-face, you can be verbose and explain things in a round-a-bout way. When you're limited to email, IM and phone, all parties need to explain themselves fully but succinctly. I find that summarising long emails into request/action points goes a long way towards getting things done well.
2. [Everyone] Have a online project tracking space. Most tend to use a ticket system or some description, where action points can be assigned to members. It wouldn't hurt to use this same space for tracking emails and sharing whiteboard ideas. Most online project apps allow for that by default.
3. [Management] Don't pester devs. If you need something urgently, set the status of the ticket, give them a call and chase them up later on in the day. **Half-hourly emails asking "is it done yet?" does more harm than good!**
4. [Management] Make sure messages get passed along. If a dev says "somebody needs to do something", it's your job to make sure the message is passed along to the right person. There are few things more annoying than passing a message to a project manager for them to accidentally sit on it. I don't want to have to chase up things like that because it's, frankly, not what I'm being paid for.
5. [Management] Make sure people have something to do. If you send them home with nothing on their task list that they can immediately action, they're not going to put in the effort. It's a damned sight harder to keep yourself productive at home than it is in the office when you've little or nothing that you can do. You might have to juggle tasks if there's a blocker.

Answer (score 4):

I work at home full time. Here are things that help in my small (6 people) team.

Set up rules for using IM. For example, allow remote workers to block off time not to be interrupted by email or IM. Require workers to keep status up-to-date somewhere (IM, Yammer, etc) which helps keep them accountable to stay on task. Stay in touch without being a distraction.

Meet in person occasionally if possible. Nothing can replace a face-to-face meeting. Skype is ok for group meetings, but not if whiteboards are involved.

Use SharedView or another screen sharing program for collaborating. Screenshots/screen captures are helpful as well to make sure both parties are on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

"Any idea how to effectively manage and collaborate with developers working remotely?"

What does "effectively" mean?  I can be negative and assume it means "with me, the project leader in control of everything".  I can be positive and assume you want people to be as effective as possible.

Sometimes, "effective" is management-speak for "under my control".  Or it means "not screwing around."

The question, then is "effectively doing what?"  Effectively "working" is rather vague.  Hence my leap to the dark side of project management.  [Which, I admit, is probably wrong.   But without specific team productivity problems, the question has no answer.]

"it's tough to work together without the benefit of a whiteboard and hand-waving"  This is only sometimes true, there are lots of replacements.  The "hand-waving" over the internet happens more slowly and more thoroughly.

The group-think around the whiteboard is fun -- it's a kind of party.  However, for some of us, it's not very productive.  I need hours to digest and consider and work out alternatives; I'm actually not effective in the group whiteboard environment.

I find it more effective to use the alternative "slow-motion" whiteboard technologies.  I like to see a draft pitch for an idea.  Comment on it.  Refine it.  A lot like a Wiki or Stackoverflow.  I really like the internet RFC model -- here's my idea; comment on it.  When there are no more improvements, that's as good as it's going to get.

Answer (score 1):

I work in Mississippi and my home office is in Michigan. I spend several hours a day pair programming with my team with ease.  The tools I use are:

- SharedView
- Remote Deskop Assistance
- Live Meeting
- Oovoo
- Skype

Depending on who and how many will depend on the tool I use.

"Use the right tool for the job and invest in a damn good headset." - Me.

Answer (score 0):

I've generally used some time of community based software such as a wiki, blog, or forum to handle the documentation areas. We also have a Cisco phone system and use some capabilities of the system. I'd also recommend live meeting or webex to do frequent team meetings. Skype and IM clients such as Live Messenger are also good tools. For the short status updates, twitter does the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the **Agile Scrum** methodology with VSTS. Scrum forces us to have daily 15 minutes meeting and small mile stones , It makes sure the effective togetherness and tight communication. Make sure you use Task,Bug assignment etc through VSTS

Answer (score 0):

I agree with John Sheehan's response.  I am a consultant and manage other consultants - both on a project basis (as PM) and on a client basis across projects.  I have worked with developers on a purely remote basis as well as telecommuting (meaning the majority of time we are co-located).  Working remotely is a matter of trust and communication.  Co-locating is best, but if you work remotely, simply create a culture of frequent communication.  IM and phone are great for this, email less so.  If you have a less than communicative co-worker, it is up to you as the manager to reach out.  Ask for status.  Force code-checkin on a frequent basis for review.

[EDIT] - Yes, don't pester and set expectations!  Be clear and concise.

Answer (score 0):

First of all use scrum (daily scrum calls, scrum board w/ burndown chart (wikis do a great job there), iteration in sprints etc). Next to that use tools that make it more easy to collaborate remotely like skype and VNC (maybe campfire?) and a wiki. I worked for 2 years on a project w/ people in 3 countries on 2 continents and various time zones and it worked quite well. The key is having tools and methodologies that make it more difficult for people to "hide", so that everything you and your team does is visible.

Answer (score 0):

I find clear communication and staying on task are challenging with virtual teams. I try to use regular scheduled update meetings (over the phone or video conference) with a written agenda to help with these challenges.

At the front on the agenda list the major milestones and the near term milestones. The first item is always "check progress" each team member simply updates us on when they expect to finish the particular tasks involved. We try not to get involved in long stories here. It's simply "what are you going to do and when".

Once the progress check is done deal with any other issues raised in during the last week and any issues the team has that can be sorted out whilst you are in the meeting. Anything let over (such as new issues raised) needs to have the question asked "who is needs to sort this out and when".

Once you set a common format for the meeting you can do this weekly in 30-45 minutes with teams of 5-8 people. Keep it short and sweet so it isn't viewed as an imposition. Keep it focused on actions and schedule so it can be valuable.

Answer (score 0):

I'm currently the PM of a smaller project that has two developers (myself and another developer that works out of the office).  We are currently having daily SCRUM meetings, which last for about 15 minutes.  We discuss what got done the previous day, what problems were encountered and what I can do to help with these problems, and what will be done tomorrow.

They're pretty quick and seemed to be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Using a Time Tracking Software for your remote employees can greatly help you in managing the team.

While hiring a remote employee, you would be concerned about,

1. The amount of time spent in getting a task done.
2. The quality of the work done.
3. Collaboration based on the progress of the project.
4. The real time progress on a task.
5. Collaborating to solve bugs and logical errors.

I was in your situation a while ago and then I tried [StaffTimerApp](https://stafftimerapp.com/) and it helped me in the following ways.

1. A Time Tracking Software gives crystal clear statistics about the time spent on getting a task done. StaffTimerApp captures screenshots and converts them into billable and non-billable hours. Hence, you would know if any time was wasted while getting the work done. You would also know the exact amount of time spent in getting the work done. If you pay your contractor by the hour, this application can help you tremendously.
2. If you use a time tracking software that captures screenshots, you can look at them to analyse the quality of work that is being delivered. I used this feature and was able to save some tasks from derailing.
3. A Time Tracking Software lets the employer know how far along the employee is with the task, hence the information extracted by Time Tracking will make collaboration easier. StaffTimerApp proved to be very helpful as I was able to collaborate with the other employees based on this information.
4. The [screen sharing](https://stafftimerapp.com/screen-sharing/) feature equipped me with the power of viewing my employee's laptop screen in real time. This way I would get to know about the progress on a task.

So you need a good Time Tracking Software with great productivity analytics and employee monitoring capabilities to feel comfortable with hiring a remote developer.